# ios textfield overlaps keyboard

Tags: ios

I have an ios app where the rootviewcontroller of the app is a custom flow controller, and there is a view hieararchy like this: 
scrollview => mainview => widgetview => textfields

When i click the textfield keyboard is overlapping bottom part of the textfield which is ok, but the strange thing is there is glitch and textfield is showing on top of the keyboard. any ideas?

[image: how it looks like]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it has been a long time since i asked this question and i forgot about that, anyway i found that these kind of rendering problems may occur when views have shadows, just disabled the shadow..